# Saved Visio drawing (VSD) as JPG, how to covert it back to a Visio file?

Tags: jpeg, microsoft-visio

I have made a class diagram and i have saved it as a JPG from Microsoft Visio.

How do I convert the JPG to a VSD file so that I can make changes to it?

Answer (score 6):

I do not know anything about the subject, but converting a picture to a vsd-file sounds impossible to me. It is the same as if you tried to convert a news magazine back to word document..? (they don't use word for that though)

Comment: Or like trying to extract the people from a photograph so you can talk to them.  Impossible.  You could load the JPG in an image manipulation program (Photoshop, PSP, The Gimp, etc) and make some changes to it.

Comment: Once a Visio document is saved as a JPG file, it loses the information necessary for Visio to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult, as saving as JPEG discards information (which parts belong together, etc.).

You *could* make the image editable by [vectorizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28computer_graphics%29) it, but even that will not give you a Visio file, just something you can edit in a vector graphics editor like [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

I'm afraid the easiest solution is to regenerate the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  But maybe you can find the last auto-recover backup file from before you saved it?

Use Open, type in %temp%*.vsd (optionally use the Views button to get more information and help you find the right one), then click the one you want, and save it normally.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/My-Office-program-did-not-open-a-recovered-file-773e6094-65c4-410c-b73c-4455a4e293f8

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would be just a hint.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Formats like JPG, GIF etc should not have been included as "Save" options, that implies there is a restore facility, Far better would have been to make these formats available on an "Export" menu.

Answer (score -1):

Double click on the image that you have saved. 
Or take that image in word file and double click there, it will directly open with visio if installed on your system.

Comment: It works only if you have pasted the figure as Visio object, not as a picture.